# iOS 8.3: UICollectionView & multithreading: What is the best approach?

Tags: multithreading, uicollectionview, ios8.3

For an iOS application wherein a `UIViewController` has a `collectionView` whose datasource (an NSArray) is contained in a separate model class. This array is getting updated [adding / removing items to it] through an `NSNotification` which in turn requires a web API call [on another thread]. When web service returns information then the datasource is updated and so also `UICollectionView` needs to be updated. This process is continuous & occurs at random times.

The question is how the `UICollectionView's` UI updation can be done in a safe manner so that it do not result in issues where `UICollectionView` start complaining that no. of rows / section before update is not same as after update
Can anybody suggest an approach so that multithreading do not have any impact on `UICollectionView` and one can safely use `UICollectionView's` various UI manipulation api like insertSections, insertItemsAtIndexPath etc. In this process the `UICollectionView` is continuously changing and so also its data source.